# Using Data::Printer with qx operator

Tags: perl

I was experimenting with the [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) module, and it worked fine until
I tried to print the return value of a system call using [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) operator:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

p qx/echo -n Hello/;
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Type of arg 1 to Data::Printer::p must be one of [@$%&] (not scalar)
```

I assume this error occurs because `qx` is not recognized as a scalar, hash, array, or function. So I tried:

```
p my $temp = qx/echo -n Hello/;
```

and it worked fine. The question is, if it is possible to avoid the use of the `$temp` variable? (I think this syntax would become annoying to use and remember in the long run)

Comment: Unlike `Data::Dumper` and `Data::Dump`, the default mode of `Data::Printer` allows you to display only the contents of variables, not arbitrary expressions

Comment: @Borodin Yes it seems so.. I wonder if it be difficult to implement the feature, or it has just not been considered for implementation yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `Data::Dumper` and `Data::Dump`, the default mode of `Data::Printer` allows you to display only the contents of variables, not arbitrary expressions

This behaviour can be circumvented by disabling the `use_prototypes` option in the `use` statement, when arrays and hashes must be passed explicitly by reference

```
use Data::Printer use_prototypes => 0, output => 'stdout';

p qx/echo -n Hello/;
```

#### output

```
"Hello"
```